# What is a safe way to create a Temp file in Java?

Tags: java, temporary-files

I'm looking for a **safe** way to create a temp file in Java.  By safe, I mean the following:

- Name should be unique, even under potential race conditions (e.g. another Thread calls the same func at the same time, or another process runs this code simultaneously)
- File should be private, even under potential race conditions (e.g. another user tries to chmod file at high rate)
- I can tell it to delete the file, without me having to do a generic delete, and risk deleting the wrong file
- Ideally, should ensure file is deleted, even if exception is thrown before I get the chance to
- File should default to a sane location (e.g. the JVM specified tmp dir, defaulting to the system temp dir)

Comment: Use `File f = File.createTempFile(prefix, extension)`. It will be placed in the temp dir. And with `f.deleteOnExit()` it will be automatically deleted on exit.

Comment: Delete on Exit will not delete the file, if the vm exits with an exception.

Comment: Use `Files.createTempFile("tempfiles", ".tmp")` instead, for enhanced security; check 2nd most voted answer.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Use [`File.createTempFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefix-", "-suffix");
//File tempFile = File.createTempFile("MyAppName-", ".tmp");
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
```

Will create a file in the temp dir, like:

> prefix-6340763779352094442-suffix

Comment: Just FYI, you dont need to worry about having a unique prefix / suffix, since Java will create a random String of numbers in between.

Comment: Super! Any problem doing a normal `tempFile.delete()` in addition to the `deleteOnExit` (since I don't want to have hordes of temp files hanging around before exit)?

Comment: No, you can do it either way.

Comment: @SRobertJames:No problems. The thing is that the _creation_ of tempfiles with predictable names imposes security problems. Once they are created in a safe way with proper permissions, they don't.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this safe, the created file is world-readable and it resides in the tmp directory which tends to be accessible to any user.

Comment: Yes, this is just the standard. You can set the temp directory, for this vm, to a safer directory, like this: `System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/somewhere/outside/mywarfile");` And set access right to the vm user only.

Comment: [CWE-379](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/379) states that this is not secure, because it creates a temporary file in a directory whose permissions allow unintended actors to determine the file's existence or otherwise read and modify the contents of that file.

Answer (score 69):

Since Java 7 there is the new file API "NIO2" which contains new methods for creating temp files and directories. See

- [createTempDirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))
- [createTempDirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory(java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))
- [createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))
- [createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))

e.g.

```
Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("tempfiles");
```

or

```
Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("tempfiles", ".tmp");
```

**Security notice:**

An important difference between `File.createTempFile()` and `Files.createTempFile` is also that the latter has more secure permission defaults.

> When no file attributes are specified, then the resulting file may
> have more restrictive access permissions to files created by the
> `File.createTempFile(String,String,File)` method.

Comment: I prefer NIO, which doesn't require a prefix.

Comment: @FranklinYu How did you manage not to specify a prefix tho?