# Opening a File in java during run time

Tags: java

What i am trying to do is have my java create a vbs file, open the file to run it, than delete it. i have covered the creating and deleting part of it but what i am trying to do it run it, and since eventually the jar will be in random places i cant open it with an exact path. Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this? Here is what i have (simplified for reading)

```
public void MapDrive() throws IOException {

    File map = new File("map.vbs");

    map.createNewFile();

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("map.vbs");

    writer.println(" VBS code here ");

    writer.close();

    map.delete();

}
```

Comment: 1. You can use interface with input where you write the path of file. 2. Use Scanner() and run your jar in console where you can write the path. 3. Open your jar in console with parameter(path) and in your code get the value of parameter.

Comment: hi. What I could think of is a temporary file placeholder on the computer where you can copy the file and then try to execute that copy?

Comment: Try [Create a temp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860167/java-safe-way-to-create-a-temp-file)