# How to convert MultipartFile properly to match for Microsoft AudioConfig?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cognitive-services, multipartfile, microsoft-speech-api

In my Spring Boot application, I accept an audiofile as MultipartFile with `@RequestParam`. I know, I can convert the file into some InputStream. I am also able to convert it into some byte array:

```
@PostMapping("/microsoft")
void transcribe(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
  InputStream inputStream =  new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream());
  byte[] byteArr = file.getBytes();

  AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.???;    //here the correct method with my file needs to be called
}
```

For transcription using Microsoft API, I need to create some `Audioconfig` object. [This is the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.audioconfig?view=azure-java-stable) to the class.
I used in the past `fromWavFileInput(...)` when I loaded a local audio file. But now, I need to be able to use the MultipartFile. I have no idea which method of the AudioConfig class I can use and how to convert the file correctly.

Comment: Why don't you create a [temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860167/what-is-a-safe-way-to-create-a-temp-file-in-java) then combine all parts from into it with [MultipartFile.transferTo](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo(java.io.File)) , and then use [AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/audioconfig?view=azure-node-latest#microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk-audioconfig-fromaudiofileoutput) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is, to create a temp file and transfer the MultipartFile into it:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefix-", "-suffix");
file.transferTo(tempFile);
```

The use `fromWavFileOutput` with the path of the temporary file:

```
AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromWavFileOutput(tempFile.getPath());
```

For me, the temp file exceeds its maximum permitted size. To get this solved, make sure to add `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1` in your *application.properties* file to set limit to infinity.